# Carregamento lento de página localmente após configurar virtual hosts

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, localhost, virtualhost

Saudações, estou tendo problemas no carregamento de paginas no meu servidor local. 
Esse problema passou a ocorrer depois que configurei 3 virtual hosts e, quando tento carregar minha pagina através dele, demora MUITO para carregar.
Alguém, por favor, poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Conseguiu resolver? Quando inspeciono os elementos no navegador, o carregamento demora uns 10s e percebi que são os js que mais demoram.